# Producing a Document Template

Tags: templates

I wanted to know how could one produce this template with borders where it has **Problem Set #5** and **18.085** and all besides the actual mathematical text within the actual document. I do want to also know how to create the **boxes** around the solutions like within the body of the document. And lastly, how to create the **date** and **page numbers** at the bottom corners of the page. I like the style of this document for writing math work and want to incorporate this for my own mathematical papers.

Another thing in mind was how can you insert code such as `MATLAB` or any other program language neatly into the document as so, seen on (Page. 8 and 9). Is that a picture snapshot of the code and then saved as a file then inserted as a graphics float?? Never seen it before in a TeX document. Another side note would be how do one strike out text in TeX, that looks to be pretty useful. Can one include that as well with your solution.

This document is here below:

[Math Document](http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.085/18085_F10_Soln5.pdf)

Thanks.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [fancyhdr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) allows you to easily customise the page headers and footers in your document.

The [amsmath](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package provides the `\boxed` command that puts formulae in boxes.

Program code is usually entered in a verbatim environment, either the standard LaTeX version or an enhanced version offered by a package such as [fancyvrb](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb).

You can strike through text using the [ulem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ulem) package, but make sure that you say `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}`, or else it will interfere with the `\emph` command.

Comment: Thank You for the quick response and information. I will see what I can do with the information provided and if I need some further assistance with formatting issues, I will `edit` with the progress of a `mwe`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That document looks like it used the [exam](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) class, which may internally use fancyhdr and other packages @Ian mentioned. I'd definitely check it out for this specific case, and possibly use the [listings](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package for the code.

Comment: +1...Hey Mike `:)`, Thanks for that article you sent. It looks good. I scanned through it, and I think that it may be on **Page 10** of the `exam` class package. Thanks. I still have to look at the `listings` for inputting code.